# Nested views "the rails way"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, routes, nested

I am working on a rails 3.2 application that has a lot of static, deeply nested pages. The architecture is as follows:

[image: menu structure]

So far, I have an `information controller` with these four methods:

- about_the_liver
- therapies
- nutrition
- liver_diseases

with the following routes:

```
get "information/therapies"
get "information/nutrition"
get "information/liver_diseases"
get "information/about_the_liver"
```

**Here are my questions:**

- First of all, these routes, as generated by the rails generator, look clumsy. Is there any way to dry them out and group them together? E.g., so that the "information/" part is not repeated so often?

I have come up with this, but I am not sure whether this is the best approach:

```
[ :therapies, :nutrition, :liver_diseases, :about_the_liver ].each do |method|
  get "information/#{method}"
end
```

- I will need views for every single menu entry that you can see in the rightmost menu. My approach is to change `liver_diseases` to being a separate controller and have 8 different views - but that can't be dry. Is there a "rails way" to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you simply put your static pages in `/public` and have them served directly from there?  If there's no rails content this would be the quickest and most efficient approach.